# css grid - hide row in media query

Tags: html, css

I'm using css grid to make my layout. I would like to hide my details row and only show sidebar row in media query (max-576px). When i want to see Details row i should do click in "Show detail" button and hide Sidebar row.  I have tried different ways but i couldn't achieve solve.

I really appreciate any helps .

[My code](https://jsfiddle.net/Adolfome9/xkmzqw0e/2/)

```css
       * {
         margin: 0;
         padding: 0;
       }


       .container {
         margin: 0;
         height: 100%;
         display: grid;
         grid-template-columns: 100%;
         grid-template-rows: 40px 1fr;
         grid-column-gap: 0;
       }

       .header {
         background-color: #ececec;
       }

       .main {
         background-color: yellow;
         display: grid;
         grid-template-columns: 40px 1fr;
       }

       .apps {
         background-color: lightgrey;
       }

       .content {
         background-color: blue;
         display: grid;
         grid-template-columns: 100%;
         grid-template-rows: auto 1fr;
       }

       .content-header {
         background-color: red;
         /* display: flex; */
       }

       .content-body {
         background-color: antiquewhite;
         display: grid;
         grid-template-columns: 250px 1fr;
         grid-template-rows: 1fr;
       }

       .sidebar-panel {
         background-color: aquamarine;
       }

       .sidebar-button,
       .detail-panel-button {
         display: none;
       }

       .details-panel {
         background-color: cyan;
       }

       @media screen and (max-width:576px) {
         .main {
           grid-template-columns: 100%;
           grid-template-rows: 1fr 40px;
         }

         .content {
           order: 1;
         }

         .apps {
           order: 2
         }

         .content-body {
           grid-template-columns: 1fr;
           grid-template-rows: 1fr;

         }

         .sidebar-panel {
           display: block;
         }

         .details-panel {
           display: none;
         }

         .sidebar-button,
         .detail-panel-button {
           display: block;
         }
       }

       button {
         background: #0084ff;
         border: none;
         border-radius: 5px;
         padding: 8px 14px;
         font-size: 15px;
         color: #fff;
       }

       #banner-message.alt {
         background: #0084ff;
         color: #fff;
         margin-top: 40px;
         width: 200px;
       }

       #banner-message.alt button {
         background: #fff;
         color: #000;
       }
```

```html
    <div class="container">
      <div class="header">
        Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Eveniet, expedita.
      </div>
      <div class="main">
        <div class="apps">
          App1 <br>
          App2
        </div>
        <div class="content">
          <div class="content-header">
            <div style="height: 40px;">
              Ribbon
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="content-body">
            <div class="sidebar-panel">
              <h3>Sidebar</h3>
              <button class="sidebar-button">Show Detail</button>
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Laboriosam reprehenderit suscipit
              molestias minus velit earum sed quasi tenetur sit voluptate.
            </div>
            <div class="detail-panel">
              <h3>Detail</h3>
              <button class="detail-panel-button">Show Sidebar</button>
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Facilis ex nam, laudantium cumque
              voluptas aliquid harum esse veniam deserunt numquam. Odit tenetur sunt, harum laborum
              voluptatibus pariatur. Ad, nemo ipsa iure recusandae dignissimos iusto odio libero sapiente
              neque! Tenetur et quam magnam, numquam assumenda a aut! Dignissimos, sit. Impedit modi
              necessitatibus alias voluptatum odio ipsum enim quam eum, harum animi quidem, itaque
            </div>

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: You want to hide the details section only ?

Comment: In @media screen and (max-width:576px) at first time i want to hide detail section, then using jquery i would like to hide hide sidebar section and show detail section.

Answer (score -1):

Damn it bro
You made a tiny little mistake. Just modify `.details-panel` to `.detail-panel`.
And pls paste this `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">` inside your `<head>` tag

Comment: I did your suggestion but it seems to doesn't work... could you please share you complete code... thanks.

Comment: This removes your details sections but you gotta tweak the apps row